# Perl UTF-8/encoding: How to detect $str1 eq $str2 to avoid MySQL round-trip?

Tags: perl, utf-8

A caller to a sub has given me a value `$new_value`. I have selected a value from a MySQL database into scalar `$current_value`. I cannot figure out how to reliably detect whether they're "identical". By identical I mean: If I update a database record with `$new_value` will that change the database state?

Boiling this down to its essence:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use utf8;
use strict;
use Encode qw(encode);
my $str = 'æøå';
my $latin1 = encode('latin1', $str);

# This in fact doesn't die. They're eq
$str eq $latin1
    or die;
```

If I update a field in a MySQL database with `$str`, I get one value back if I re-select it - a UTF-8 encoded value. Using `$latin1`, the database field ends up with another value - a latin1/ISO-8859-1 encoded value.

The original problem I'm debugging updates a field with `CHARSET=latin1` but the symptoms show up equally well with a simple:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:mysql:mysql",
    'user',
    'pass',
    # No, we don't have these options on our DB handles
    # Introducing them now would causes (too) many regression issues
    # for us, as in other places also, values are latin1 encoded,
    # not UTF-8 encoded.
    # mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,
    # mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1`
);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT CONCAT(?)')
    or die;
$sth->execute($val);
my ($return_val) = $sth->fetchrow_array();
```

Since `$str` and `$latin1` result in different values after a MySQL round-trip, I'd like to detect that they are, in fact, not equal. So assuming the current value in the database is a correctly encoded latin1 `æøå` that I've already `SELECT`-ed that into a `$current_value` scalar then my question boils down to coding:

```
sub new_value_will_change_database {
    my ($current_value, $new_value) = @_;
    # How to write I write this sub, so it returns true for $str 
    # and false for $latin1 from above?
    ...
}
```

How do I accomplish that? The only difference I've been able to detect, is that the UTF8-flag is enabled on `$str`, but not on `$latin1`. However, I also seem to remember that if I'm checking the UTF-8 flag, my code is broken...

### Fuller Debugging Script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use utf8;
use strict;
use feature qw(:5.10);

use Encode qw(encode is_utf8);
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = 'æøå';

my $latin1 = encode('latin1', $str);

my $utf8upgraded = $latin1;
utf8::upgrade($utf8upgraded);

# $str, $latin1 and $utf8upgraded are all eq each other:
$str eq $latin1
    or die;
$str eq $utf8upgraded
    or die;
$latin1 eq $utf8upgraded
    or die;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:mysql:mysql",
    'user',
    'pass',
);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT CONCAT(?)')
    or die;

sub mysql_roundtrip {
    my ($val) = @_;
    $sth->execute($val);
    my ($concat) = $sth->fetchrow_array();
    return $concat;
};

foreach my $set (
    [ 'str', $str ],
    [ 'latin', $latin1 ],
    [ 'utf8upgraded', $utf8upgraded ],
) {
    my ($disp, $val) = @$set;

    my $hex = $val;
    $hex =~ s/(.)/sprintf "%X", ord($1)/ge;

    my $dumper = Data::Dumper->new([substr $val, 0, 1])->Terse(1)->Dump;
    chomp $dumper;
    printf "%-13s: val:%s mysql:%s is_utf8:%d hex:%s dumper0:%s\n",
        $disp,
        $val,
        mysql_roundtrip($val),
        is_utf8($val),
        $hex,
        $dumper;
}
```

produces this output:

```
str          : val:��� mysql:æøå is_utf8:1 hex:E6F8E5 dumper0:"\x{e6}"
latin        : val:��� mysql:��� is_utf8:0 hex:E6F8E5 dumper0:'�'
utf8upgraded : val:��� mysql:æøå is_utf8:1 hex:E6F8E5 dumper0:"\x{e6}"
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you already tried but you can use `utf8::is_utf8($str)` to check if the UTF-8 flag is set for `$str`

Comment: Thanks, @ikegami. I'm really, really hoping there is another way.  The database is all latin1/ISO-8859-1. So `/mysql_enable_utf8(mb4)?/` seems inapproriate given the perldoc DBD::mysql saying: "mysql_enable_utf8: This attribute determines whether DBD::mysql should assume strings stored in the database are utf8." Also, I can't imagine the number of regressions this would cause in other places.

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland: So assuming I bite the bullet and look at the UTF-8 flag, how do I use that info in `sub new_value_will_change_database`? Always return true if `utf8::is_utf8($new_value)`? I can construct a test case that will break that by updating the database beforehand with `$str`. That would lead to a UTF-8 encoded value that is identical to `$current_value`. The sub would then return true when it should've returned false.

Comment: @Peter V. Mørch The best way would be to convert the database to UTF-8. If this isn't possible you will experience a lot of problems. BTW: As far as I know Latin-1 in MySQL is CP1252, whereas Latin-1 in Perl's Encode is strict ISO-8859-1 (no €-sign). Using encode/decode with wrong encodings will damage characters.

Comment: @HelmutWollmersdorfer: At 300 k lines of perl code, this is not feasible.

Comment: @Peter V. Mørch I have 10 years experience with larger code bases in Perl 'mixed mode'. Seven years ago I got 650 k lines of Perl code to maintain, using byte mode, working on UTF-8 in byte mode and MySQL in UTF-8 (and some fields in Latin-1). This is never ending debugging. Some modules from CPAN rely on character mode. Get UTF-8 strings from somewhere (Web-form), store it in a Latin-1 field in MySQL -> damage, because the original string was not in the Latin-1 range of codepoints. Sooner or later you need to use UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: @ikegami: I'm trying to understand: If I set `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1` and then give DBI only UTF-8 data, DBI+MySQL will correctly convert to whatever charset is defined for the database fields (latin1 in our case). Now all my perl logic can use UTF-8 and the DB can use latin1 and I don't have to care. Now I only need to convert all the other logic in the rest of the app to use UTF-8 encoding instead of latin1, because with latin1 encoded data, DBI now dies: `DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Incorrect string value: '\xE6\xF8\xE5' for column 'name'`. That conversion isn't going to be today :-)

Comment: Inserting into an iso-latin-1 field is more like `SELECT CONVERT(? USING LATIN1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution we're going with (for now at least):

```
sub mysql_value_latin1 {
    my ($val) = @_;
    # See text - this looks strange - but works!
    if (is_utf8($val)) {
        $val = encode('utf8', $val);
    } else {
        $val = encode('latin1', $val);
    }
    return $val;
}

sub new_value_will_change_database {
    my ($current_value, $new_value) = @_;
    my $mysql_new_value = mysql_value_latin1($new_value);
    return $current_value ne $mysql_new_value;
}
```

Thanks @ikegami and @HelmutWollmersdorfer for your input on this issue. You both suggest these options for the `$dbh`:

```
mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,     # Decodes string received from the DB.
mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1,  # Sets the encoding used for the connection.
```

As I've pointed out that will cause an unpredictable amount of regressions in our code base since the handles are shared by many libraries.

The advantages of `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1` are clear: Perl code sends correctly encoded UTF-8 data to MySQL, which then converts it to Latin1 (CP 1252) and puts it in the database. We are guaranteed that data is stored properly, and we can use UTF-8 in Perl, not caring about the Latin1-ness of the database.

There are disadvantages also: Any data that is not valid UTF-8 will be rejected by `DBI` or `DBD::mysql` (I'm not clear which), and my testing has also shown that MySQL will reject storing data in a Latin1 table that isn't valid Latin1 (CP 1252).  So we need to be more explicit about encoding our data before sending it to the database - probably a good thing actually.

`mysql_enable_utf8 => 0` appears to behave quite strangely. It appears, that if the UTF-8 flag on Perl scalars is set, then data will be UTF-8 encoded and otherwise data will be left at Perl's internal encoding (ISO-8859-1/Latin1). This data is then sent to MySQL and stored in the Latin1 table, wether or not the data actually is valid CP 1252 data. With `mysql_enable_utf8 => 0` I was able to store all chars in 0x00-0xFF without problems, even though some are not valid CP 1252 characters.

If anybody can find a failing test for `@tests`, please let me know.

The task at hand in the OP was to predict whether a given scalar would change the value of the database if handed to MySQL for an UPDATE, and the `sub new_value_will_change_database` does exactly that - without changing properties of the `$dbh`. That is why I prefer this solution to the OP.

I do agree that a better technical solution is to go the `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1` route, but it is also the poorer business decision because of the effort involved to address the (potential) regressions.

### Fuller Debugging Script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use utf8;
use strict;
use feature qw(:5.10);

use Encode qw(encode is_utf8);
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = 'æøå';

my $latin1 = encode('latin1', $str);

my $utf8upgraded = $latin1;
utf8::upgrade($utf8upgraded);

# $str, $latin1 and $utf8upgraded are all eq each other:
$str eq $latin1
    or die;
$str eq $utf8upgraded
    or die;
$latin1 eq $utf8upgraded
    or die;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:mysql:mysql",
    'user',
    'pass',
);

$dbh->do(q(
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (
        name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
    ) CHARSET=latin1;
));
$dbh->do(q(
    INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('');
));

sub mysql_roundtrip_convert {
    my ($val) = @_;
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT CONVERT(? USING LATIN1)');
    $sth->execute($val);
    my ($concat) = $sth->fetchrow_array();
    return $concat;
}

sub mysql_roundtrip_column {
    my ($val) = @_;
    my $updateSth = $dbh->prepare('update test set name=?');
    $updateSth->execute($val);
    my $getSth = $dbh->prepare('select name from test');
    $getSth->execute();
    my ($value) = $getSth->fetchrow_array();
    return $value;
};

sub mysql_roundtrip {
    my ($val) = @_;
    # Check that these two are the identical:
    my $column = mysql_roundtrip_column($val);
    my $convert = mysql_roundtrip_convert($val);
    $column eq $convert
        or die "column ne convert";
    return $column;
}

sub mysql_value_latin1 {
    my ($val) = @_;
    # See text - this looks strange - but works!
    if (is_utf8($val)) {
        $val = encode('utf8', $val);
    } else {
        $val = encode('latin1', $val);
    }
    return $val;
}

sub new_value_will_change_database {
    my ($current_value, $new_value) = @_;
    my $mysql_new_value = mysql_value_latin1($new_value);
    return $current_value ne $mysql_new_value;
}

my @tests = (
    [ 'str', $str ],
    [ 'latin', $latin1 ],
    [ 'utf8upgraded', $utf8upgraded ],
    map { [ 'char ' . $_ , 'char' . chr($_) ] } ( 0x00 .. 0xFF ),
);

foreach (@tests) {
    my ($disp, $val) = @$_;
    my $mysql_roundtrip = mysql_roundtrip($val),
    my $mysql_value_latin1 = mysql_value_latin1($val);
    $mysql_value_latin1 eq $mysql_roundtrip
        or die "mysql_value_latin1 ne mysql_roundtrip";
}
print "All test are fine\n";
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly: Most of your 300 k lines of old code in Latin1 mode will store `ø` as one byte `F8` and the new code will store `ø` as UTF-8 encoded 2 bytes `C3B8`? And both old and new code will read and write the same fields of the database?

Comment: No, both old and new code store `ø` as `F8`. Further, we had a bug where UTF-8 input was not encoded as Latin1. Easily fixed. A side effect was that there was a `if ($new_value ne $old_value) { fork_background_process }` that got forked often because of the misencoding, where it was only supposed to fork off for database changes. I wanted to fix that too, leading to this question.

Answer (score 3):

When you try to place a character in an iso-latin-1 field and the character isn't in the Windows-1252 charset, a question mark is inserted instead.

So assuming you properly send the text to the database<sup>[1]</sup>, the following will work:

```
sub will_change_db_virtual {
   my ($current_text, $new_text) = @_;

   state $re;
   if (!$re) {
      my $cp1252_charset = decode('cp1252', (join '', map chr, 0x00..0xFF), sub { "" });
      $re = qr/[^\Q$cp1252_charset\E]/;
   }

   $new_text =~ s/$re/?/g;
   return $new_text ne $current_text;
}
```

Test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;                             # Source code encoded using UTF-8.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # Terminal uses UTF-8.

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use DBI;
use Encode qw( decode encode encode_utf8 );

sub mysql_roundtrip {
    my ($val) = @_;

    my $dbh = DBI->connect(
        'dbi:mysql:...', '...', '...',
        {
            PrintError => 1,
            RaiseError => 1,
            mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,     # Decodes string received from the DB.
            mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1,  # Sets the encoding used for the connection.
        },
    );

    my $got = $dbh->selectrow_array(
        'SELECT CONVERT(? USING LATIN1)',
        undef,
        encode_utf8($val),
    );

    return $got;
}

sub will_change_db_real {
   my ($current_text, $new_text) = @_;
   return mysql_roundtrip($new_text) ne $current_text;
}

sub will_change_db_virtual {
   my ($current_text, $new_text) = @_;

   state $re;
   if (!$re) {
      my $cp1252_charset = decode('cp1252', (join '', map chr, 0x00..0xFF), sub { "" });
      $re = qr/[^\Q$cp1252_charset\E]/;
   }

   $new_text =~ s/$re/?/g;
   return $new_text ne $current_text;
}

my @tests = (
    [ "abcd\x{000E9}fg", "abcd\x{000E9}fg" ],
    [ "abcd\x{00113}fg", "abcd\x{00113}fg" ],
    [ "abcd?fg",         "abcd\x{00113}fg" ],
    [ ( decode('cp1252', (join '', map chr, 0x00..0xFF), sub { "" }) ) x 2 ],
);

for (@tests) {
    my ($current_text, $new_text) = @$_;

    my $got_real = will_change_db_real($current_text, $new_text);
    my $got_virtual = will_change_db_virtual($current_text, $new_text);

    printf("current:%vX new:%vX changed? real:%d virtual:%d result:%s\n",
        $current_text,
        $new_text,
        $got_real ? 1 : 0,
        $got_virtual ? 1 : 0,
        ($got_real ? 1 : 0) ^ ($got_virtual ? 1 : 0) ? "fail" : "pass"
    );
}
```

Test output:

```
current:61.62.63.64.E9.66.67 new:61.62.63.64.E9.66.67 changed? real:0 virtual:0 result:pass
current:61.62.63.64.113.66.67 new:61.62.63.64.113.66.67 changed? real:1 virtual:1 result:pass
current:61.62.63.64.3F.66.67 new:61.62.63.64.113.66.67 changed? real:0 virtual:0 result:pass
current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new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changed? real:1 virtual:1 result:pass
```

---

1. You don't in your example. You don't encode the values passed to execute according to the encoding used by the connection.

Comment: Thanks again, @ikegami for your time and effort. Much appreciated. Before I become stubborn and continue resistance, I'll go to bed and think about it... :-)

Comment: Fixed a bug. `Encode::encode('iso-latin-1', $_)` considers U+0080 a valid iso-latin-1 char, but MySQL doesn't.

Comment: @ikegami For the full CP1252 range we can create the test characters using `[ (join('', map decode('CP1252',encode('iso-latin-1',chr($_))), 0x00..0xFF)) x 2 ]`. Then substitute the 5 invalid characters using `$new_text =~ s/[\x{FFFD}]/?/g;`. This roundtrips with real UPDATE and SELECT. This doesn't need `CONVERT(? USING LATIN1)`,  `encode_utf()` and `mysql_enable_utf8mb4`.

Comment: @Helmut Wollmersdorfer, You are mistaken about not needing `CONVERT(? USING LATIN1)`. If you remove the cast, you aren't simulating INSERTING into the OP's database. 2) You are mistaken about not using `mysql_enable_utf8mb4`. One is restricted as to which characters one can send when this isn't used. 3) You are mistaken about encode not being needed. One should always use `encode` (with the approporiate encoding) or `utf8::upgrade` (with `mysql_enable_utf8mb4` only) on text passed to DBI because of a design bug that can cause data corruption.

Comment: @Helmut Wollmersdorfer, 4) Finally, `s/[\x{FFFD}]/?/g` -- better written as `s/\x{FFFD}/?/g` or `s/\N{REPLACEMENT CHARACTER}/?/g`-- is nowhere near an appropriate replacement for `s/[^\x00-\x7F\x81\x8D\x8F\x90\x9D\xA0-\xFF]/?/g`. It doesn't even pass all of the already-provided test cases.

Comment: @ikegami I trust your experience concerning encoding and protocol. But the regular expression does not predict the behaviour of codepoints above `\xFF`. E. g. \x{20AC}, €, \N{EURO SIGN} will be stored as \x80, and roundtrips (UTF-8 -> CP1252 -> UTF-8). This behaviour is of practical relevance, because (MS Windows) users insert the characters specific to CP1252 often. Thus `$prediction = decode('CP1252',encode('CP1252',$unicode_string));`is a more complete prediction. What it does not catch exactly are the 5 codepoints `[\x81\x8D\x8F\x90\x9D]`, which can be stored in MySQL-Latin1.

Comment: @Helmut Wollmersdorfer, You are right that the charset MySQL calls latin1 is actually cp1252 (though the non-latin1 codepoints of cp1252 are 20AC, 201A, 192, etc; not 80, 82, 83, etc). Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-we-sets.html) MySQL stores the character range of CP1251 encoding if configured for Latin1, i. e. UTF-8 is converted to CP1251. Characters not assigned in CP1252 change to a question mark. Code points `[\x81\x8D\x8F\x90\x9D]` are stored unchanged.

The simplest way for a prediction is to implement the same behaviour in a subroutine `prediction()`. It can help to detect following situations:

```
my $predict = predict($new_string);
if ($new_string ne $predict) {
  print "WARN: $new_string will not sore correctly in DB\n";
}
elsif ($existing_db_string ne $predict) {
  print "INFO: $new_string will change DB string\n";
}
```

Roundtrip test over a large range of characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # Terminal uses UTF-8.

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use DBI;
use Encode qw( decode encode encode_utf8 );

sub mysql_roundtrip {
  my ($val) = @_;

  my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    'DBI:mysql:database=testlat;host=192.168.1.3;port=3306',
    'userid',
    'passwd',
    {
        PrintError => 1,
        AutoCommit => 1,
        RaiseError => 1,
        mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,
        mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1, 
    }
  ) or die $DBI::errstr;

  my $sql = 'UPDATE testlat SET name = ? WHERE id = 1;';
  my $dbz = $dbh->do($sql, undef, encode_utf8($val));

  my ($got) = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT name FROM testlat WHERE id=1');

  return $got;
}

sub predict {
  my $uni_string = shift;

  my @chars = split(//,$uni_string);
  my @predict;
  for my $char (@chars) {
    if ($char =~ /[\x81\x8D\x8F\x90\x9D]/) {
      push @predict, $char;
    }
    else {
      my $predict = decode('CP1252',encode('CP1252',$char));
      if ($predict ne $char) { $predict = '?'; }
      push @predict, $predict;
    }
  }
  return join('',@predict);
}

my $fails = 0;
print "*** test via database \n";
for my $number (0x00..0x2122) {
  my $uni_char = chr($number);
  my $predict = predict($uni_char);

  my $got = mysql_roundtrip($uni_char);

  if ($predict ne $got) {
    $fails++;
    printf("FAIL uni:%.4X predict:%.4X got:%.4X\n",
      $number,
      ord($predict),
      ord($got)
    );
  }
}

print "FAILS: $fails\n";
```

Output:

```
$ perl utf8_latin1_mysql_test2.pl
*** test via database 
FAILS: 0
```

This passes the tests for code points `0x00..0x2122` and can be expected to work for the whole Unicode range.

Comment: Another solution with the `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1, mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1` options. My handles _don't_ have that.... And I'd _really_ like to avoid that because spread over 300 k lines of perl code values are latin1 encoded before sending to the database, not utf8 encoded. As the answer from @ikegami also pointed out, setting these options makes it predictable, but it introduces unacceptable regressions for us. :-( I've edited the question to be explicit about not having the `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1, mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1` options.

Comment: Also, the `mysql_enable_utf8` option is marked as exprimental in `perldoc DBD::mysql` from Debian stable. The experimental status was only [lifted in May 2016](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-perl/packages/libdbd-mysql-perl.git/commit/?id=026fa02d80afc7f3473e67b9f63fe1b74575da3e). But I wish we had used it from the start... :-(

Comment: I use `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1` in production on Debian 6, 7 and 8.

Comment: Sure. The perldoc for `mysql_enable_utf8` does also say that "This attribute determines whether DBD::mysql should assume strings stored in the database are utf8." and "This option is experimental", right? Apparently it is fine to ignore these two sentences, but I just wanted to point out that I did RTFM! :-) Again, I wish we had gone the `mysql_enable_utf8` route, but that ship has sailed...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you're printing out what you want to be printing out.  And I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.  The two strings *are* the same, just represented differently.

If we print out a bit more information by changing your `for` loop like this:

```
foreach my $set (
                 [ 'str', $str ],
                 [ 'latin', $latin1 ],
                 [ 'utf8upgraded', $utf8upgraded ],
                ) {
    my ($disp, $val) = @$set;

    my $hex = $val;
    $hex =~ s/(.)/sprintf "%X", ord($1)/ge;

    my $dumper = Data::Dumper->new([substr $val, 0, 1])->Terse(1)->Dump;
    chomp $dumper;
    my $mysql = mysql_roundtrip($val);
    my $dumper_mysql = Data::Dumper->new([substr $mysql, 0, 1])->Terse(1)->Dump;
    (my $hex_mysql = $mysql) =~ s/(.)/sprintf "%X", ord($1)/ge;
    chomp $dumper_mysql;
    printf "%-13s: val  :%s is_utf8:%d hex:%s dumper0:%s\n" .
        "%-13s  mysql:%s is_utf8:%d hex:%s dumper1:%s\n",
    $disp, $val, is_utf8($val), $hex, $dumper,
    "",    $mysql, is_utf8($mysql), $hex_mysql, $dumper_mysql;
}
```

then we get the output of whether the mysql concat output is utf8 or not, and what the hex values there are, etc.  And then, playing around to get it all working properly (see elsewhere on how much fun unicode, or encoding in general, is to play with), I made the following additional changes:

1. `binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';` to get perl to output properly
2. `utf8::decode($concat)` in your `mysql_roundtrip` function to properly decode the text back into perl's format.

Once I had done these, I got val and mysql to show up the same, always as æøå.

Comment: I'm not worried about printing out the debug data with the right encoding. I'm concerned with setting the values in the database with the right encoding, and being able to detect in Perl (without a MySQL roundtrip) whether an input value would change the value in the database if an UPDATE was issued. I'll clarify the question.